# Cloud SQL ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, econnrefused

I am trying to use node.js App Engine with Cloud SQL, with MySQL. I am following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql?hl=pt-br) but my app engine does not connect with cloud sql and print this error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect (net.js:1086)
}
```

Comment: For connecting from App Engine Flexible, follow this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-sql